# Parsing large JSON with Boolean and Array

Tags: android, json, parsing, streaming, gson

what's up?

I have a JSON which has a Boolean as item 1 and an array of "Socio" objects as item 2 and I have to read with streaming because it's very large.

My +5.0MB JSON is kind of: `{"response":true,"result":[{SOCIO OBJECT}, {SOCIO OBJECT}...]`

My first code (which threw `OutOfMemoryError` on API 8, 9) was:

```
            InputStream source = f.retrieveStream(params[0]);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);

            Respuesta response = gson.fromJson(reader, Respuesta.class);
            Socio[] socios = response.getSocio();
```

My new code for streaming is:

```
            InputStream source = f.retrieveStream(params[0]);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(source,"UTF-8"));
            reader.skipValue(); // Because I have to skip the response... Am i doing this right??
            lista = new ArrayList<Socio>();
            Socio soc;
            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                soc = gson.fromJson(reader, Socio.class);
                lista.add(soc);
            }
            reader.endArray();
            reader.close();
```

But it throws this Exception when it's almost loaded:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was END_DOCUMENT at line 1 column 4716089

on the line which has the code: `reader.beginArray();`

[This is](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming) where I based my streaming reading.

I've read a lot of parsing with GSON, but I can't find anything for parsing an specific array from a JSON file. I only know to do it with Android Json library but I need to use GSON. I also browsed the 10 first pages of [this search](https://www.google.it/search?q=streaming%20read%20gson%20parser&oq=streaming%20read%20gson%20parser) on Google and I found no clear response, and I understood [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924550/java-gson-http-response-difficult-parsing) but it's working with objects which has names, so I cannot work with that for array.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.
Rafael.

Comment: I said hello at the beginning but automatically, SO deletes it ... :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your streaming code is wrong, the first skipValue actually makes you skip the whole document.

Try this out:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(source,"UTF-8"));
jsonReader.beginObject();
while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
    String strName = jsonReader.nextName();
    if (strName.equals("response")) {
        reader.skipValue();
    }
    else if (strName.equals("result")) {
        jsonReader.beginArray();
         while (reader.hasNext()) {
            soc = gson.fromJson(reader, Socio.class);
            lista.add(soc);
        }
        jsonReader.endArray();
    }
}
jsonReader.endObject();
...
```

Comment: I'm kinda disappointed of myself since I'm more analyst than coder ... 

Thank you very much, your help was very great

Comment: You´re welcome Rafa, and don´t be to hard on yourself, we all have our days where we wish we performed better.